# Excel crashes when timestamp updates

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a code for updating of timestamp whenever changes made to any sheet but it is getting crashed on my partner excel-365. Here is my code of sheet8 same is for other sheets as well:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Sheet8.Cells(2, 3).Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End Sub
```

Comment: Is Sheet8 the same sheet where this code is running, or a different sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're updating a cell on the same worksheet, you need to suspend events otherwise when you write the timestamp you're going to re-trigger the event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False  '<< turn off events
    Me.Cells(2, 3).Value = Format(Now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    Application.EnableEvents = True   '<< re-enable events
End Sub
```

Note also you can use `Me` in a worksheet code module to refer to the worksheet.